# Pandas file IO Read Error

Tags: pandas

New to pandas, running into an error consistently with WinXP file path, for example:

```
names1880 = pd.read_csv('C:\Documents and Settings\Foo\My Documents\pydata-book\pydata-book-master\ch02\names\yob1880.txt', names=['name', 'sex', 'births'])
```

Keep getting an error as follows:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 names1880 = pd.read_csv('C:\Documents and Settings\Foo\My Documents\pydata-book\pydata-book-master\ch02\names\yob1880.txt', names=['name', 'sex', 'births'])
```

From reading thru available documentation, haven't isolated if its a problem with my syntax or a parser issue.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to include the entire traceback, not just the first line.

Comment: Also use raw-strings or forward-slashes or escape your backslashes in your file path.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you put `r` in front of the string, the `\n` is being interpreted as a newline:

```
In [1]: 'C:\Documents and Settings\Foo\My Documents\pydata-book\pydata-book-master\ch02\names\yob1880.txt'
Out[1]: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Foo\\My Documents\\pydata-book\\pydata-book-master\\ch02\names\\yob1880.txt'
```

vs

```
In [2]: r'C:\Documents and Settings\Foo\My Documents\pydata-book\pydata-book-master\ch02\names\yob1880.txt'
Out[2]: 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\Foo\\My Documents\\pydata-book\\pydata-book-master\\ch02\\names\\yob1880.txt'
```